# How to deploy a Custom ArcGIS Pro Configuration?

Tags: arcgis-pro, deployment, arcgis-pro-sdk

I have created a Custom [ArcGIS Pro Configuration](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2017/01/19/introducing-arcgis-pro-sdk-configurations/) by customizing this sample: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk-community-samples/tree/master/Framework/ConfigWithMap

This is working as expected on my System.

I now wish to deploy this Configuration to all GIS workstations in my company, and set up ArcGIS Pro to use this as the default configuration.

How Do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you're still looking for a distribution solution:

1. Create a shortcut of ArcGISPro.exe, and
2. add the configuration to the 'target'field (image below).
3. Lastly copy the custom configuration to the user's machine @ C:\Users\Public\Documents\ArcGIS\ArcGISPro\Configurations.

[image: shortcut command line]

"Typically, you create a desktop short-cut per configuration you wish to run. Each shortcut contains the relevant /config:{Configuration_name} argument to make launching the different configurations trivial; this also allows you to easily jump between different configurations and the default application simply by starting Pro with a different desktop shortcut."

4. Below method forces the configuration to the user's local machine registry, and is harder to change once installed:

"A configuration can also be specified in the registry. When the registry is used, the configuration named in the registry is always run for every session of Pro. The registry overrides any configuration specified on the command line..."

"...Configurations use the same installation pattern as add-ins. Double-click the .proConfigX file to run "RegisterAddin.exe". "RegisterAddin.exe" validates the configuration and copies it to the configurations' well-known folder: C:\Users\Public\Documents\ArcGIS\ArcGISPro\Configurations. Users are given an opportunity to review the author, description, version, and digital signature information of the configuration before proceeding. If a configuration has the same name as an existing configuration installed to the same folder (default folder or well-known folder), the existing configuration will be overwritten. "

https://github.com/esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProConcepts-Configurations